# npm installation error in Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

I am using node v4.4.3 and trying to `npm install` in my Angular project but it throws some error after installation:

```
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@2.2.4 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@2.2.4 wants @angular/common@2.2.4

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.2.4 wants @angular/common@2.2.4

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.2.4 wants @angular/common@2.2.4

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.2.4 wants @angular/common@2.2.4

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ng2-bootstrap@1.1.16 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ng2-ckeditor@1.1.9 wants @angular/common@^2.1.0 || ^4.0.0

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ng2-file-upload@1.2.1 wants @angular/common@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ng2-sharebuttons@1.1.5 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     /Users/affanfaisal/workspace/konmari/konmari-api-2/konmari-web-app-client/npm-debug.log
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you show your `package.json` ?

Answer (score 1):

In [angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#devenv) they clearly mentioned

> Verify that you are running at least node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x by
>   running node -v and npm -v in a terminal/console window. Older
>   versions produce errors, but newer versions are fine.

so you need **npm > 3.X** and **node > 6.X.X**

Comment: Interestingly https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages says Node v4 and up, perhaps due to additional packages in the QuickStart.

Comment: there is a substantial change in `npm v3 from v2` but not in node,so node version `v4 or v5 or v6` does not matter what you have but it best to have the `latest LTS`, thats why i mentioned node `6.X.X` but not `6.9.X`

Answer (score 0):

You should update npm by simply using command

**npm install -g npm**

This might solve the error